# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "quien a hierro mata, a hierro muere / termina"?

Tags: refranes

Siempre me gustó la canción de Mano Negra "Bala perdida" de su fantástico disco [Casa Babylon](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_Babylon).

En ella, se oye en algún momento una frase que siempre me generó curiosidad:

> Quien a hierro mata a hierro termina...

Googleando esta frase me encuentro que probablemente proviene de la canción ["Pedro Navaja" de Rubén Blades](http://genius.com/Ruben-blades-pedro-navaja-lyrics/).

Una búsqueda más extensiva me lleva a encontrar referencias a otra expresión similar **"Quien a hierro mata, a hierro muere"**, que [el Centro Virtual Cervantes describe](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=59343&Lng=0) como:

> Significado: Por lo general, uno recibe o experimenta el mismo daño
>   que hizo a otro.

Sin embargo, sigue pareciéndome una expresión rara en todos los casos, de formación extraña y difícil de interpretar. ¿A qué frase original puede referirse que con el tiempo se ha ido *acortando* hasta llegar a la forma actual? ¿Qué simboliza "hierro" en este caso?

Comment: Siempre entendí que "hierro" se refería a un arma (blanca), tipo una espada, o la punta de una lanza o flecha. Cierto que estas armas son de acero, no hierro, pero entendía que en este contexto se usaba como un equivalente. Aquellos que tanto usan la espada no sólo se ganan muchas enemistades, sino que tarde o temprano encuentran a alguien que la maneja mejor que ellos y por lo tanto, como dices,  " experimentan el mismo daño" o de la misma manera que hicieron a otros.

Comment: Equivalence en inglés: He who lives by the sword, dies by the sword.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Este refrán viene del latín:

> Qui gladio [ferit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferio#Latin) gladio [perit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pereo#Latin).

Literalmente:

> Quien con espada hiere, por espada muere.

O sea:

> El que con una espada gana su vida, también con la misma arma la pierde.

La palabra *gladio* es en el caso ablativo de [*gladius*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gladius#Inflection): quiere decir *con espada*.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! No sabía del término _gladio_, que me descubre cómo _gladiador_ tiene un sentido muy claro.

Answer (score 13):

El origen de la expresión «quien a X mata, a X muere» es mencionado en el siguiente pasaje bíblico [Mt 26:52](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026:52):

> *Pero uno de los que estaban con Jesús, extendiendo la mano, sacó su espada, e hiriendo a un siervo del sumo sacerdote, le quitó la oreja.*
>
> *Entonces Jesús le dijo:*
>
> *—Vuelve tu espada a su lugar; porque todos los que tomen espada, a espada perecerán.*

En otras traducciones se hizo uso de la <s>metáfora</s> sinécdoque del hierro que bien explica @Diego. Al seleccionar el enlace puedes ir usando el selector al lado de «search» para ver diferentes traducciones.

El original griego usa μάχαιράν, que es, efectivamente, una espada corta o daga, usada para apuñalar.

Comment: Gran repuesta. El original podría se incluso más antiguo que eso. La _Ley del Talión_, del Código de Hammurabi (Babilonia, siglo XVIII a. C.) ya decía "Ojo por ojo y diente por diente", es decir, retribución de la misma manera que el se cometió el crimen. Aun así parece una fuente probable para el refrán.

Comment: Me gustaría aceptar ambas respuestas, pero lamentablemente no puedo. ¡Mil gracias por esta respuesta, tan bien documentada como siempre!

Comment: Algo curioso que me viene a la mente es que esta frase se habla mayormente en Latinoamerica. Dado que nuestro español viene de España, y éste es un país sumamente católico, me inclino a pensar que esta es la respuesta correcta. Puede que me equivoque.

Comment: @scubaFun ¿Por qué te parece que el refrán es más conocido en Latinoamérica que en España misma?  Puede ser que sí, pero nunca se me ocurrió. ¿Existen algunos datos concretos que sugieran esto?

Comment: @tchrist Desafortunadamente, no tengo datos concretos...

Answer (score 2):

En hebreo existe una frase de origen arameo (por supuesto todavía más antiguo que el griego):

> על דאטפת אטפוך, וסוף מטיפייך יטופון
>   ("Como asesinaste a una persona, y provocaste que su cuerpo flote en el río, a ti te sucedió lo mismo, y a quienes así te hicieron, les ocurrirá lo mismo...)

Answer (score 1):

Me fijé ahora en la definición de "a" en el DRAE:

> [**a**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=002rZ9U%7C003Ov93&o=h)
>
> ...
>
> 14. prep. con. Quien a hierro mata, a hierro muere.

Lo que clarifica la pregunta al ver que, en este caso, la frase es equivalente a:

> Quien a hierro mata, *con* hierro muere.

Answer (score -1):

La frace aparece en el libro el arte de la guerra que según el autor SUN ZUT fue escrito 2500 años. Mi duda es que cultura, región, o filósofo fue el que la empleo por primera vez como enseñanza

Answer (score -2):

Tengo entendido que es mas profundo que todo eso.

*hierro* y *yerro* se pronuncian parecido y el dicho original venia a ser:

> quien por error mata, por error muere.

Es por aquello de que el reo suele escudarse en que el "no queria matar a nadie, que no sabia que la victima falleceria tras asestarle 72 puñaladas y aplastarle el craneo con una roca".

http://es.thefreedictionary.com/yerro

Comment: No creo. Otras respuestas muestran antecedentes muy antiguos en idiomas en que no se produce la similitud fonética entre *hierro* y *yerro*.

Comment: Creo que yerras.